# Converting a base 10 number to other bases 2 without built in Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, for-loop

I am new to coding and javascript and was asked, for an assignment, to convert base 10 numbers to a binary base without using specific Javascript built in methods (like alert(a.toString(16))), and I am only allowed to use loops,arrays and functions. This is what i have so far:

```
var number = prompt("Enter an unsigned base 10 number");
    if (number>=0) {
        var base = prompt("Enter b for binary, o for octal, or h for hexadecimal");

        if (base=="h"||base=="H") {
            ;
        }
```

So as you can see, I don't have much to go on. I was curious as to what equation or formula I would use to convert the base 10 number, as well as how i'm supposed to show A=10, B=11, C=12 and so forth for a hexadecimal base. Any help would  be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to convert to Binary (2 based)  or Hexadecimal (16 based)?

Comment: To all three, binary, hexadecimal and octogonal. Depending on what base the user chooses to convert to, the code will run for that specific base.

Comment: You seem to be after an algorithm (e.g. [*Change a number from base 10 to any other base*](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Introduction/frombase10.htm)). Once you have found that, you should try to program it. That is the step this site is for.

Comment: A hint: use the remainder of the division by 2 to convert a number in binary; you will need a loop. The remainder (modulus), in Javascript it is the `%` operator. I will not give you more, since this is supposed to be an assignment and you should work it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks you guys! This really helped

Comment: The remainders produce the converted number, but when they are in reverse order. How do I get them to flip order?

Comment: Push them onto an array and then either reverse the array using `Array.reverse()` or, if that is not allowed, iterate through the array from last to zeroth index building your string that way. Probably the latter way is fastest, since you're going to have to iterate anyway, given your assignment's constraints.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** *This is a rather complicated way to do it,
as Alnitak showed me (see discussion below).
It is more a scibble, or the long way by foot.*

**Short explanation:**

If we want to get the binary of the decimal number 10,
we have to try `2^n` so that `2^n` is still smaller than 10.
For example `2^3 = 8` (that is OK). But `2^4 = 16` (thats too big).
So we have `2^3` and store a `1` for that in an array at index 3.

Now we have to get the rest of `10-2^3`, which is 2, and have to
make the same calculation again until we get a difference of zero.

At last we have to reverse the array because its the other way arround.

```js
var a = prompt("Enter an unsigned base 10 number");
var arr = [];
var i = 0;

function decToBin(x) {
  y = Math.pow(2, i);
  if (y < x) {
    arr[i] = 0;
    i++;
    decToBin(x);
  }  else if (y > x) {
    i--;
    newX = (x - Math.pow(2, i));
    arr[i] = 1;
    i = 0;
    decToBin(newX)
  } else if (y == x) {
    arr[i] = 1;
    result = arr.reverse().join(); 
  }
  return result;
}

var b = decToBin(a); // var b holds the result

document.write(b);
```

Comment: That appears needlessly complicated - my version is `function decToBin(x) { return (x ? decToBin(Math.floor(x / 2)) : '') + (x % 2) }`    (with the caveat that this always adds a leading zero)

Comment: and if the numbers are constrained in the range 0 .. 2^31 - 1 the `Math.floor(x / 2)` can be replaced with `x >>> 1`

Comment: @Alnitak Thx for your great advice. You are a much better coder. I am still learning a lot. But i try to help as much as i can. Actually i am a designer.

Comment: @Alnitak It would be nice if you explain your code. I am able to understand it acutally. How it the binary string getting stored?

Comment: it's just accumulated via the recursion

Comment: @Alnitak I like your function, but i don't undestand it fully.
It would be very nice, if you could explain this short code a little bit.
I understand it is a recursive function and the left hand side seems to be only the "loop-condition", while the right side prints out its value (or accumulates it).

Comment: The right side doesn't print it - it _concatenates_ the newly calculated digit with the value returned from the recursive step.  The `?:` conditional operator is there to terminate the recursion.

Comment: Algorithmically, this is just the simple "least significant digit first" algorithm.  If the number is even, you output a zero, otherwise a 1, then you divide the number by two, repeat, until there's nothing left.